# How to select rows in pandas dataframe based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements

I have a huge data and my python pandas dataframe looks like this:

| HR | SBP | DBP | SepsisLabel | PatientID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 92 | 120 | 80 | 0 | 0 |
| 98 | 115 | 85 | 0 | 0 |
| 93 | 125 | 75 | 0 | 0 |
| 95 | 130 | 90 | 0 | 1 |
| 102 | 120 | 80 | 1 | 1 |
| 109 | 115 | 75 | 1 | 1 |
| 94 | 135 | 100 | 0 | 2 |
| 97 | 100 | 70 | 0 | 2 |
| 85 | 120 | 80 | 0 | 2 |
| 88 | 115 | 75 | 0 | 3 |
| 93 | 125 | 85 | 1 | 3 |
| 78 | 130 | 90 | 1 | 3 |
| 115 | 140 | 110 | 0 | 4 |
| 102 | 120 | 80 | 0 | 4 |
| 98 | 140 | 110 | 0 | 4 |

I want to select only those rows based on PatientID which have SepsisLabel = 1. Like PatientID 0, 2, and 4 don't have sepsis label 1. So, I don't want them in new dataframe. I want PatientID 1 and 3, which have SepsisLabel = 1 in them.

I hope you can understand  what I want to say. If so, please help me with a python code. I am sure it needs some condition along with iloc() function (I might be wrong).

Regards.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to select rows from a DataFrame based on column values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071871/how-to-select-rows-from-a-dataframe-based-on-column-values)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) with [`GroupBy.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.any.html) for test if at least one `True` per groups and filtering by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df1 = df[df['SepsisLabel'].eq(1).groupby(df['PatientID']).transform('any')]
```

Or filter all groups with `1` and filter them in [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
df1 = df[df['PatientID'].isin(df.loc[df['SepsisLabel'].eq(1), 'PatientID'])]
```

If small data or performance not important is possible use [`DataFrameGroupBy.filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.filter.html):

```
df1 = df.groupby('PatientID').filter(lambda x: x['SepsisLabel'].eq(1).any())
```

---

```
print (df1)
     HR  SBP  DBP  SepsisLabel  PatientID
3    95  130   90            0          1
4   102  120   80            1          1
5   109  115   75            1          1
9    88  115   75            0          3
10   93  125   85            1          3
11   78  130   90            1          3
```